# Behavior of sh script depending on how it is called

Tags: bash, sh

A have a simple sh `script1` that calls an even simpler `script2`.
I get four different results for the number and value of arguments of script2 if I run, in a bash shell, `./script1`, `./script1 1`, `. script1` or `. script1 1`.

Could anybody explain why, please?

The scripts are:

script1

```
#!/bin/sh
sourceRc()
{
    echo "@script1: inside a fuction"
    . /home/user/test/script2 2
}
echo "@script1: # OF ARGUMENTS = "$#
sourceRc
echo "@script1: outside a fuction"
. /home/user/test/script2 2
```

script2

```
echo "@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = "$#
echo "@script2: ARGUMENT IS = "$1
```

Their permissions are

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user mygroup  209 May 14 15:32 script1
-rw-r--r--  1 user mygroup   38 May 14 15:29 script2
```

And the results are

```
user@machine:~/test$ ./script1
@script1: # OF ARGUMENTS = 0
@script1: inside a fuction
@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = 0
@script2: ARGUMENT IS = 
@script1: outside a fuction
@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = 0
@script2: ARGUMENT IS = 

user@machine:~/test$ ./script1 1
@script1: # OF ARGUMENTS = 1
@script1: inside a fuction
@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = 0
@script2: ARGUMENT IS = 
@script1: outside a fuction
@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = 1
@script2: ARGUMENT IS = 1

user@machine:~/test$ . script1
@script1: # OF ARGUMENTS = 0
@script1: inside a fuction
@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = 1
@script2: ARGUMENT IS = 2
@script1: outside a fuction
@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = 1
@script2: ARGUMENT IS = 2

user@machine:~/test$ . script1 1
@script1: # OF ARGUMENTS = 1
@script1: inside a fuction
@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = 1
@script2: ARGUMENT IS = 2
@script1: outside a fuction
@script2: # OF ARGUMENTS = 1
@script2: ARGUMENT IS = 2
```

Comment: your results seem to be incorrect. please run the scripts again.

Comment: You should always be quoting variable expansions (not expanding them outside of quotes). (Not that this matters here as-such it is just a general practice thing.)

Comment: what is `sh` on your machine?

Comment: Do your results change if you use `/bin/bash` to run `script1` specifically? What version of `bash` and `sh` is this?

Comment: I have just editted the question. sh 0.5.7-4ubuntu1 gives this behaviour. bash 4.3-7ubuntu1.5 give reasonable results.

Comment: Try changing shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` and check whether results are different. They are different on my machine.

Comment: Note that the second two examples it's ignoring the shebang line and executing with your current shell, while in the first two examples you are using `/bin/sh` to execute the commands.  Likely, you are using `bash` in the second two and `sh` in the first two.

Comment: @EtanReisner,  Arkadiusz Drabczyk and Eric Renouf, thank you for the comment. Now I understand that different shells are in use at the different examples. The sh behaviour is really strange.

Comment: `sh` appears to just not support explicit arguments to sourced scripts. So `script2` reports the arguments to the top-level script.

Answer (score 0):

[The POSIX standard for `.`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) indeed does not require it to accept arguments, instead using the positional parameters of the script/function that calls it. Explicit arguments are allowed as an extension:

> The KornShell version of dot takes optional arguments that are set to the positional parameters. This is a valid extension that allows a dot script to behave identically to a function.